# Loading external javascript library with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I built a small javascript library I need to use inside a BackboneJS project.
My problem is, I have an issue to use the library. I think I did something wrong, when I'm trying to access it, I got an "undefined".

Some code below, I simplified it.

The library looks something like that - myLibrary.js:

```
(function() {
    var myLibrary = this;

    var initialize = function() {
        console.log('initialize');
    };

    myLibrary.otherFunction = function() {
        console.log('otherFunction');
    };
    return myLibrary;
})();
```

I putted my library in my requirejs config:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: "js/jquery"
        myLibrary: "js/myLibrary"
    }, 
    shim: {
        myLibrary: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});
```

And I'm trying to use my library inside a BackboneJS view

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'backbone',
  'myLibrary'
], function($, Backbone, myLibrary){
    'use strict';

    return Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function() {
            console.log(myLibrary); 
            //myLibrary is undefined here!
            //I'd like to access myLibrary as an object 
            //to access my functions inside..
        }
    });
});
```

The library is loaded. I can see it in the Network tab of my developer bar.

If you have any idea what's wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you've got things right now, your `myLibrary` script is actually running, but the return value (`return myLibrary;`) is being discarded because it's not being assigned to anything. You can do one of two things:

You can assign the return value to something on the global object and update your `shim` config:

```
window.myLibrary = (function() {
    var myLibrary = this;

    var initialize = function() {
        console.log('initialize');
    };

    myLibrary.otherFunction = function() {
        console.log('otherFunction');
    };
    return myLibrary;
})();

requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: "js/jquery"
        myLibrary: "js/myLibrary"
    }, 
    shim: {
        myLibrary: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: "myLibrary"
        }
    }
});
```

Or, better yet, actually use `define` inside your library:

```
define(["jquery"], function ($) {
    var myLibrary = this;

    var initialize = function() {
        console.log('initialize');
    };

    myLibrary.otherFunction = function() {
        console.log('otherFunction');
    };
    return myLibrary;
});
```